# UI question: Designing for widescreen and 4:3 aspect ratios simultaneously?

Tags: layout, user-interface

I'm working on a UI which needs to work in different aspect ratios, 16:9, 16:10, 4:3

The idea is conceptually simple: Everything is centered to the screen in a rough 4:3 area and anything outside this portion of screen has basic artwork, so something like this:

[image]
(not drawn to scale)

Where the pink area represents whre all the UI objects are positioned and the blue area is just background and effects.

The trick is in usability, if I pass in coordinates (0,0) in a 4:3 aspect ratio environment (0,0) would be the top left of the screen. However if I'm in a 16:9 environment (0,0) needs to get renormalized based on the new aspect ratio for it to be in the appropriate place. So my question is: How can I achieve this?

edit: for clarification this is basically for a UI system and while I listed the ratios above as 4:3, 16:9, 16:10 it should be able to dynamically adjust values for whatever aspect ratio it is set to.

edit 2: Just to add more details to the situation: When the positions fo rsetting are passed in they are passed in as a % of the screens current widht height, so basically setting position x would be: [pos x as portion of screen]*SCREEN_WIDTH where screen width is the width of the current screen itself.

Comment: Where do you input your coordinates?

Comment: Is this like an STB, where there will be a setting in the configs for outputting in 16:9 or 4:3? If so, can you read that setting, and adjust the UI accordingly so I don't get an annoying little UI in the middle of my nice large display?

Comment: I guess we need to know what level you are creating the UI - is it at the HTML level, the UI Toolkit level, or on the metal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer seems to be an offset. Since 4x3 is 16x9, it appears you want a 16x9 screen to have 2x9 bands to the left and the right. Hence, the X offset should be (2/16) * width.

For 16x10 screens, the factor is slightly more complicated: 4x3 is 13.33x10, so you have edges of width 1.67, and the X offset should be (1.67/16) * width = (5/48)* width.

Answer (score 1):

So ... Can't you just come up with an abstraction layer, that hides the differences? One idea could be to model a "border" around the active area, that gets added. For 4:3 displays, set the border size to 0 to make the active area cover the full screen.